# How to modify the cell value of a table in an ppt file using apache POI

Tags: apache-poi, hslf

I am facing an issue with replacing the table cell value in a slide in 
a ppt. First i have used version 3.10.1 but it was not working, later i 
tried with 3.8 it was updating the cell values. Can you please let me know 
if the latest version supports this or not.

I am able to override the cell value which already has some values, but if 
it has blank values then the cell value is not getting updated.

Comment: Can you post the code that doesn't work?

Comment: Hi,                                                                 
Please find below the code ,dataRow is a list 
                                                        
TableCell cell = table.getCell(row, j);

            
if (null == cell) {
               
 continue;
           
 }

                
String str = String.valueOf(dataRow.get(dataRowIndex++));
       

if (addCellColor) {
   
     
 str = setColor(cell,str);
     
           }
              
        

cell.setText(str);